# MarkLogic cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery dates and $property-name

Tags: json, path, marklogic

```
let uris=cts.uris( null,null,cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery(               
              "dateStart"
            ,
            '>=',
            xs.date('2000-01-01'),[],0.5
          )).toArray()
```

The above results in

> [javascript] XDMP-ELEMRIDXNOTFOUND: 
>       cts.uris(null, null, cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery("dateStart", ">=", xs.date("2000-01-01"), [], 0.5))
>       -- No date element range index for dateStart

The data does exists in some documents as follows

```
"times": [
   {
      "type": "openingHours", 
      "value": []
    }, 
    {
   "type": "eventTimes", 
   "value": {
       "dateStart": "2020-02-01", 
       "dateEnd": "2020-02-01", 
        "timeStart": "07:00", 
        "timeEnd": "20:00"
    }
}
],
```

I have tried a fully qualified path of

```
/instance/times[contains(type,'eventTimes')]/value/dateStart
```

Comment: It tells you it didn't find an appropriate index to use with the range query. Did you create one?

Comment: Please can you explain what it means in rlation to an Index in this context?
All I am trying to do is select documents with a start date greater than this date and all searches point to this function. All examples show this working (given the simplistic examples)

Comment: So for each field I want to do a simple is greater than query I need to set up a range index in the console. This seems excessive and an administration nightmare. There must be a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious in the documentation for the function [jsonPropertyRangeQuery in the MarkLogic documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/cts.jsonPropertyRangeQuery) but for this to work a element range index needs to be built prior to this working,

But it is relatively simple to set up. Just follow the steps in [Defining Element Range Index documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/admin/range_index#id_51346).

There was a catch. Since we are using a Data-Hub each redeploy overwrote the index set up and it was lost.

Found that in `Data-hub/src/main/mlconfg/databases/final-database.json` the JSON had a json file range-element-index: I just added the details for each index I wanted to setup meaning they were auto built executing: `./gradlew mlredeploy`.

```
{
  "database-name": "%%mlFinalDbName%%",
  "range-element-index": [
    {
      "scalar-type": "date",
      "namespace-uri": "",
      "localname": "dateStart",
      "collation": "",
      "range-value-positions": true,
      "invalid-values": "reject"
    },
    {
      "scalar-type": "date",
      "namespace-uri": "",
      "localname": "dateEnd",
      "collation": "",
      "range-value-positions": true,
      "invalid-values": "reject"
    }
  ],
  "schema-database": "%%mlFinalSchemasDbName%%",
  "triggers-database": "%%mlFinalTriggersDbName%%",
  "triple-index": true,
  "collection-lexicon": true,
  "uri-lexicon": true
}
```